# Here Maps, how do I add a new UI Button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, here-api

I have a default interactive Nokia Here Maps v3 map set up it has multiple markers in a group on the map.

I would like to add a button or other ui element to the map that can be pressed and when it does calls a function to zoom in as tight as I can around all the markers in the group.  However, I can't find any example code of adding a new ui element, other than an infobubble, or the default ui elements for the map, which I do not want.

What I was wanting was something like the pano button, but in the top left of the map that when clicked would call my setBounds Function to zoom out to encompass all markers in the gorup.

Here is my current javascript code for my map.

```
// VUE
var vue1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
      behavior: null,
      centerCoords: { lng: #centerLon#, lat: #centerLat# },
      defaultLayers: null,
      devices: null,
      markerGroup: null,
      map: null,
      platform: null,
      ui: null,
  }),
  created: function(){
    // Initialize the platform object:
    this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'app_id': 'AN ID WOULD GO HERE',
      'app_code': 'A CODE WOULD GO HERE'
    });

    this.defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
  },
  mounted: function(){
    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    this.map = new H.Map(
      document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
      this.defaultLayers.satellite.traffic,
      {
          center: this.centerCoords,
          zoom: 15,
      }
    );

    // Make Map interactive
    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    this.behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map));

    // Create the default UI Components
    this.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, this.defaultLayers, 'en-US');
    this.ui.setUnitSystem(H.ui.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL);

    this.setMarkers();
    setTimeout(this.setBounds, 250);
    setInterval(this.setMarkers, 1 * 60 * 1000);
  },
  computed:{
  },
  methods:{
      setBounds: function(){
          this.map.setViewBounds(this.markerGroup.getBounds());
      },
      setMarkers: function(){
          let self = this;
          // if already present remove markerGroup from map
          if(self.markerGroup){
              self.markerGroup.removeAll();
          }

          //get request
          $.get(
              '/api/v1/getMarkers',
              data => {
                  let zIndex = 1;
                  self.devices = data;

                  // create new marker group from get request.
                  self.markerGroup = new H.map.Group();

                  // add marker group to the map
                  self.map.addObject(self.markerGroup);

                  // add each marker to the marker group
                  self.devices.forEach((el, ind, arr) => {
                      self.addMarkerToGroup(
                          self.markerGroup,
                          {lat: el.latitude, lng: el.longitude},
                          '<div>' + el.serial + '</div>'
                      );
                  });

                  self.map.addEventListener('tap', evt => {
                      if(evt.target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker){
                          // increase z-index of the marker that was tapped
                          evt.target.setZIndex(zIndex++);
                      }
                  });

                  self.markerGroup.addEventListener('tap', evt => {
                      let bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
                          content: evt.target.getData()
                      });
                      self.ui.addBubble(bubble);
                  }, false);
              },
              'json'
          );
      },
      addMarkerToGroup: function(group, coordinate, html){
          let marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
          marker.setData(html);
          group.addObject(marker);
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can give this a go:

```
inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {   function tempCtor() {}  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;   childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;   childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();   childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;   childCtor.base = function(me, methodName, var_args) {
    var args = new Array(arguments.length - 2);
    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      args[i - 2] = arguments[i];
    }
    return parentCtor.prototype[methodName].apply(me, args);   }; };

var ZoomTo = function(opt_options) {   'use strict';   var options = opt_options || {};

  H.ui.Control.call(this);   this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);

  // create a button element   this.increaseBtn_ = new H.ui.base.Button({
    'label': '<svg class="H_icon H_icon" viewBox="0 0 25 25">' +
      '<path d="M 18.5,11 H 14 V 6.5 c 0,-.8 -.7,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5 -.8,0 -1.5,.7 -1.5,1.5 V 11 H 6' +
      '.5 C 5.7,11 5,11.7 5,12.5 5,13.3 5.7,14 6.5,14 H 11 v 4.5 c 0,.8 .7,1.5 1.5,1.5 .8,0 1.5,' +
      '-.7 1.5,-1.5 V 14 h 4.5 C 19.3,14 20,13.3 20,12.5 20,11.7 19.3,11 18.5,11 z" />' +
      '</svg>',
    'onStateChange': this.onButtonClick   });

  //add the buttons as this control's children   this.addChild(this.increaseBtn_);

  this.setAlignment(options['alignment'] || 'top-right');

  this.options_ = options; }; inherits(ZoomTo, H.ui.Control);

ZoomTo.prototype.onButtonClick = function(evt) {   'use strict';   if (evt.currentTarget.getState() === 'down') {
    console.log('Zoom to the set of markers');   } };

var zoomTo = new ZoomTo(); ui.addControl('zoomToMarkers', zoomTo);
```